# I want to know simplest catalog service available for Kubernetes Google Cloud Shell

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, aws-service-catalog

I am unable to install any easy to use service catalog for google cloud shell.
I tried open service broker for azure but failed to install and use the service.
Please help.

Comment: The service catalog requires a cluster running Kubernetes 1.7 or higher. Are you getting any specific errors? This documentation may guide you in installing a [service catalog](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/add-on/service-catalog/install-service-catalog).

Comment: can you provide more details about your cluster, the steps you are using and the error message, if any.

Comment: I am using the steps in this link : https://www.linux.com/tutorials/set-cicd-pipeline-kubernetes-part-1-overview/  for my Ubuntu 18.04 (Minikube CI CD setup)

Comment: If you are using [service catalogs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/add-on/service-catalog/install-service-catalog) with GKE then please follow this guide: 

If you are setting up a Minikube cluster then this guide may help you setup service-catalog for a local cluster - These 2 guides might help [1](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/service-catalog/install-service-catalog-using-helm/) [2](https://github.com/manifoldco/service-catalog-tutorial)